# Month name as a string

Tags: android, calendar

I'm trying to return the name of the month as a String, for instance "May", "September", "November".

I tried:

```
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

However, this returns integers (5, 9, 11, respectively). How can I get the month name?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Use [getDisplayName](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getDisplayName%28int,%20int,%20java.util.Locale%29).

For earlier API's use `String.format(Locale.US,"%tB",c);`

Comment: I got a problem : getDisplayName(month, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US) And Eclipse is telling me Calendar.LONG or Calendar.SHORT don't exist.

Comment: That's very strange. You're using `java.util.Calendar` and not some other `Calendar` class, right?

Comment: yes. It looks like the getDisplayName() and associated Calendar.LONG and Calendar.SHORT are API level 9 only. So,it work for level 9, but I need for level 7 :(

Comment: Maybe use [`java.util.Formatter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html)?

Comment: Maybe this can be ok,but how to use it ?:S

Comment: `Formatter f = new Formatter();` (optionally you can give it a locale) then `String monthName = f.format("%tB",c).toString();` or `%tb` for short name.

Comment: Or you can try MByD's solution.

Comment: I would like to use this method with Formatter, but I get that format() is undefined for  type Formatter.

Comment: Strange. How about `monthName = String.format(Locale.US,"%tB",c);`?

Comment: also using Locale.getDefault() instead of Locale.US could be a good idea :)

Comment: In Russian it returns wrong value. `String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%tB", Month.JANUARY)` returns `января` instead of `январь`.

Answer (score 188):

Use this :

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());
```

Month name will contain the full month name,,if you want short month name use
this

```
 SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
 String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: "MMMM" would be enough for the first case.

Answer (score 156):

For getting month in string variable use the code below

For example the month of September:

M -> 9

MM -> 09

MMM -> Sep

MMMM -> September

```
String monthname=(String)android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM", new Date())
```

Comment: yes, thanks, it works like a charm, in all languages I use (french, english, german)

Answer (score 69):

**"MMMM" is definitely NOT the right solution (even if it works for many languages), use "LLLL" pattern with `SimpleDateFormat`**

The support for 'L' as ICU-compatible extension for stand-alone month names was added to Android platform on [Jun. 2010](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/143e8c9cf91cfc01c3c91c8e93cad661ec7554ee%5E%21/luni/src/main/java/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.java).

Even if in English there is no difference between the encoding by 'MMMM' and 'LLLL', your should think about other languages, too.

E.g. this is what you get, if you use `Calendar.getDisplayName` or the "MMMM" pattern for January with the Russian `Locale`:

**января** (which is correct for a complete date string: "**10 января, 2014**")

but in case of a stand-alone month name you would expect:

**январь**

The right solution is:

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "LLLL", Locale.getDefault() );
 dateFormat.format( date );
```

If you are interested in where all the translations come from - [here is the reference](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/by_type/date_&_time.gregorian.html) to gregorian calendar translations (other calendars linked on top of the page).

Comment: 'LLLL' is only available since Java 8, you can use 'MMMM' with SimpleDateFormat and it works perfectly fine for standalone version as well.

Comment: to be clear, in Russian the translation of "Января" is the genitive case, meaning "of January" whereas "Январь" is nominative, meaning just "January".  there may be other Slavic languages with this distinction such as Ukrainian and Serbian.  It's just grammatical and usually not too important.  But the use cases given in this answer are grammatically correct: use MMMM for complete dates and LLLL when displaying the month on its own if you want to be as correct as possible.

Comment: thank you, I was struggeling with Russian lang case :)

Comment: was struggling with this for like 2 days. man, you are lifesaver!

Comment: From Java 9, the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#month) docs say that "MMMM" _on its own_ is the same as "LLLL" (and "MMM" as "LLL"), i.e., the "standalone" form. And I can confirm that in the [Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/qGW5_hpgX). Not sure about Java 8. However, although the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat#month) have the same text, my tests (up to API 32) indicate that "MMMM" is always the "format" form, and is different from "LLLL". Grrr...

Comment: It requires full date (not only month).

Answer (score 36):

As simple as this

```
mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();    
String month = mCalendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
```

Calendar.LONG is to get the full name of the month and Calendar.SHORT gives the name in short.
For eg: Calendar.LONG will return January
Calendar.SHORT will return Jan

Comment: Great answer. I was setting the calendar by myself for alarm and needed to get the month name later. Perfect answer.Thank you

Comment: It shows current month. In Russian it gives wrong value: `декабря` instead of `декабрь`.

Answer (score 13):

I keep this answer which is useful for other cases, but @trutheality answer seems to be the most simple and direct way.

You can use [DateFormatSymbols](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html)

```
DateFormatSymbols(Locale.FRENCH).getMonths()[month]; // FRENCH as an example
```

Comment: Works and do not include API34 deprecated Date().

Answer (score 8):

Russian.

```
Month
.MAY
.getDisplayName(
    TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE ,
    new Locale( "ru" , "RU" )
)
```

> май

English in the United States.

```
Month
.MAY
.getDisplayName(
    TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE ,
    Locale.US
)
```

> May

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/yYVYqm).

### ThreeTenABP and java.time

Here’s the modern answer. When this question was asked in 2011, `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` were commonly used for dates and times even though they were always poorly designed. That’s 8 years ago now, and those classes are long outdated. Assuming you are not yet on API level 26, my suggestion is to use the ThreeTenABP library, which contains an Android adapted backport of java.time, the modern Java date and time API. java.time is so much nicer to work with.

Depending on your exact needs and situation there are two options:

1. Use `Month` and its `getDisplayName` method.
2. Use a `DateTimeFormatter`.

### Use Month

```
    Locale desiredLanguage = Locale.ENGLISH;
    Month m = Month.MAY;
    String monthName = m.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, desiredLanguage);
    System.out.println(monthName);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> May

In a few languages it will make a difference whether you use `TextStyle.FULL` or `TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE`. You will have to see, maybe check with your users, which of the two fits into your context.

### Use a DateTimeFormatter

If you’ve got a date with or without time of day, I find a `DateTimeFormatter` more practical. For example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter monthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM", desiredLanguage);

    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2019, 5, 31, 23, 49, 51, 0, ZoneId.of("America/Araguaina"));
    String monthName = dateTime.format(monthFormatter);
```

I am showing the use of a `ZonedDateTime`, the closest replacement for the old `Calendar` class. The above code will work for a `LocalDate`, a `LocalDateTime`, `MonthDay`, `OffsetDateTime` and a `YearMonth` too.

What if you got a `Calendar` from a legacy API not yet upgraded to java.time? Convert to a `ZonedDateTime` and proceed as above:

```
    Calendar c = getCalendarFromLegacyApi();
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = DateTimeUtils.toZonedDateTime(c);
```

The rest is the same as before.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: It's strange but `getDisplayName...` returns right string, but in some cases returns number.

Comment: @CoolMind Yes, I have observed that for a few locales too. On my openjdk-18.0.1.1 it does not happen. I haven’t tried on Android.

Answer (score 6):

The only one way on Android to get properly formatted stanalone month name for such languages as ukrainian, russian, czech

```
private String getMonthName(Calendar calendar, boolean short) {
    int flags = DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_NO_MONTH_DAY | DateUtils.FORMAT_NO_YEAR;
    if (short) {
        flags |= DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_MONTH;
    }
    return DateUtils.formatDateTime(getContext(), calendar.getTimeInMillis(), flags);
}
```

Tested on API 15-25

Output for **May** is **Май** but not **Мая**

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use `Calendar` object and `Locale`, because month names are different for different languages:

```
// index can be in range 0 - 11
private String getMonthName(final int index, final Locale locale, final boolean shortName)
{
    String format = "%tB";

    if (shortName)
        format = "%tb";

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, index);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    return String.format(locale, format, calendar);
}
```

**Example for full month name:**

```
System.out.println(getMonthName(0, Locale.US, false));
```

Result: `January`

**Example for short month name:**

```
System.out.println(getMonthName(0, Locale.US, true));
```

Result: `Jan`

Answer (score 2):

A sample way to get the date and time in 
this format "2018 Nov 01 16:18:22" use this

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
         dateFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting a standalone month name is surprisingly difficult to perform "right" in Java. (At least as of this writing. I'm currently using Java 8).

The problem is that in some languages, including Russian and Czech, the standalone version of the month name is different from the "formatting" version. Also, it appears that no single Java API will just give you the "best" string. The majority of answers posted here so far only offer the formatting version. Pasted below is a working solution for getting the standalone version of a single month name, or getting an array with all of them.

I hope this saves someone else some time!

```
/**
 * getStandaloneMonthName, This returns a standalone month name for the specified month, in the
 * specified locale. In some languages, including Russian and Czech, the standalone version of
 * the month name is different from the version of the month name you would use as part of a
 * full date. (Different from the formatting version).
 *
 * This tries to get the standalone version first. If no mapping is found for a standalone
 * version (Presumably because the supplied language has no standalone version), then this will
 * return the formatting version of the month name.
 */
private static String getStandaloneMonthName(Month month, Locale locale, boolean capitalize) {
    // Attempt to get the standalone version of the month name.
    String monthName = month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, locale);
    String monthNumber = "" + month.getValue();
    // If no mapping was found, then get the formatting version of the month name.
    if (monthName.equals(monthNumber)) {
        DateFormatSymbols dateSymbols = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale);
        monthName = dateSymbols.getMonths()[month.getValue()];
    }
    // If needed, capitalize the month name.
    if ((capitalize) && (monthName != null) && (monthName.length() > 0)) {
        monthName = monthName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(locale) + monthName.substring(1);
    }
    return monthName;
}

/**
 * getStandaloneMonthNames, This returns an array with the standalone version of the full month
 * names.
 */
private static String[] getStandaloneMonthNames(Locale locale, boolean capitalize) {
    Month[] monthEnums = Month.values();
    ArrayList<String> monthNamesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Month monthEnum : monthEnums) {
        monthNamesArrayList.add(getStandaloneMonthName(monthEnum, locale, capitalize));
    }
    // Convert the arraylist to a string array, and return the array.
    String[] monthNames = monthNamesArrayList.toArray(new String[]{});
    return monthNames;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will provide current date and month:

```
 fun getDateTime(): String? 
  {
   val dateFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM")
   val date = Date()
   return dateFormat.format(date)
  }
```