# How can I get Month Name from Calendar?

Tags: java, calendar

Is there a oneliner to get the name of the month when we know:

```java
int monthNumber  = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
```

Or what is the easiest way?

Comment: @anyone_reaching_this_issue : This question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192781/month-name-as-a-string) mentions getDisplayName() and other intesreting tricks

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```java
String getMonthForInt(int num) {
    String month = "wrong";
    DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols();
    String[] months = dfs.getMonths();
    if (num >= 0 && num <= 11) {
        month = months[num];
    }
    return month;
}
```

Comment: DateFormatSymbols implementation was changed in JDK 8, so getMonths method doesn't return correct values for all Locale's anymore: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html

Comment: could you give a workaround/working solution for JDK8?

Comment: when would you get a month as a number?

Comment: Mickey to answer your question, here is how you get month as int and use it -  public static void main(String[] args) {
  int month;
  GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
  month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);

  System.out.println("Current month is  " + (month + 1) + " and Month name is " + getMonthForInt(month));

 }

 static String getMonthForInt(int num) {
  String month = "wrong";
  DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols();
  String[] months = dfs.getMonths();
  if (num >= 0 && num <= 11) {
   month = months[num];
  }
  return month;
 }

Answer (score 212):

You can achieve it using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), which is meant to format date and times:

```java
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: This will work but I would like to get the string repr. of the month when I know the index of it. I think I will use the other approaches, thanks.

Comment: this helped me to get the current month name. although i used ("MMMM") to get the full month name instead of a shortened one.

Answer (score 83):

As simple as this

```
mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();    
String month = mCalendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: The use of Calendar abstraction is the most elegant solution in my opinion. +1

Comment: Wrong! The problem will be in languages with cases.
For example, in Slavic locales it will return month in genitive case, for example, for October in ru-RU locale you will receive `октября` instead of `Октябрь`, which you probably expect.

Answer (score 42):

This is the solution I came up with for a class project:

```
public static String theMonth(int month){
    String[] monthNames = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    return monthNames[month];
}
```

The number you pass in comes from a `Calendar.MONTH` call.

Comment: This is useful for me `new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(cal.getTime());`

Comment: this is a weak solution, how about jan, feb etc. not addition to January February etc.  this will not cover all the situation

Comment: Well, you should add 1 to the month. Arrays start from 0.

Comment: this is bad, you are re-inventing java ?

Comment: This works for english speaking users. What about the others?

Comment: @MickeyPerlstein No. That's not 'reinventing' (as you put it) Java. And it's not 'bad' either. That's simply a way to do it. Besides that this is based on not having to use the Calendar class (or at least you don't have to use it - though if you want the current month maybe so) which might be desirable in some cases. Sure it's only for English but that's besides the point.

Comment: @Pryftan you're right I meant reinventing the operating system locales and creating a mirror based on your english language. good luck localizing that mess

Answer (score 40):

If you have multi-language interface, you can use `getDisplayName` to display the name of month with control of displaying language.

Here is an example of displaying the month name in English, French, Arabic and Arabic in specific country like "Syria":

```java
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(c.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH ) );
System.out.println(c.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.FRANCE ) );
System.out.println(c.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, new Locale("ar") ) );
System.out.println(c.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, new Locale("ar", "SY") ) );
System.out.println(c.getTime().toString());
```

The result is:

```
January
janvier
يناير
كانون الثاني
Sat Jan 17 19:31:30 EET 2015
```

Comment: Which java version is this ?

Answer (score 17):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "LLLL", Locale.getDefault() );
dateFormat.format( date );
```

For some languages (e.g. Russian) this is the only correct way to get the stand-alone month names.

This is what you get, if you use `getDisplayName` from the `Calendar` or `DateFormatSymbols` for January:

**января** (which is correct for a complete date string: "**10 января, 2014**")

but in case of a stand-alone month name you would expect:

**январь**

Comment: Is a correct answer for RU locale. Very weird tho, that android SDK does not contain 'LLLL' spec.

Answer (score 12):

## Joda-Time

How about using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). It's a far better date-time API to work with (And `January` means january here. It's not like Calendar, which uses `0-based` index for months).

You can use [`AbstractDateTime#toString( pattern )`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#toString(java.lang.String)) method to format the date in specified format:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.now();
String month = date.toString("MMM");
```

### Month Name From Number

If you want month name for a particular month number, you can do it like this:

```
int month = 3;
String monthName = DateTime.now().withMonthOfYear(month).toString("MMM");
```

### Localize

The above approach uses your JVM’s current default Locale for the language of the month name. You want to specify a Locale object instead.

```
String month = date.toString( "MMM", Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

Comment: thanks but I am happy with my old `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`

Comment: @ogzd. Your wish. But you should sure give it a try, and I bet you'll love sing it.

Comment: @ogzd. I posted the way to get month name from month number. BTW, why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 11):

## `Month::getDisplayName`

Since Java 8, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum. The [`getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)) method automatically localizes the name of the month.

Pass:

- A [`TextStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/TextStyle.html) to determine how long or how abbreviated.
- A [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) to specify the human language used in translation, and the cultural norms used for abbreviation, punctuation, etc.

Example:

```java
public static String getMonthStandaloneName(Month month) {
    return month.getDisplayName(
        TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, 
        Locale.getDefault()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 10):

It might be an old question, but as a one liner to get the name of the month when we know the indices, I used

```
String month = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[monthNumber - 1];
```

or for short names

```
String month = new DateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths()[monthNumber - 1];
```

Please be aware that your `monthNumber` starts counting from 1 while any of the methods above returns an array so you need to start counting from 0.

Answer (score 4):

This code has language support.
I had used them in Android App.

```
String[] mons = new DateFormatSymbols().getShortMonths();//Jan,Feb,Mar,... 

String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();//January,Februaty,March,...
```

Comment: This works perfectly, the comments are just a tiny bit completely wrong though

Answer (score 3):

I found this much easier(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/enum.html)

```
private void getCalendarMonth(Date date) {      
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    Month month = Month.of(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));       
    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    System.out.println(month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, locale));
    System.out.println(month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.NARROW, locale));
    System.out.println(month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, locale));
}
```

Comment: doesn't `Month` start its index with January = 1, whereas Calendar starts with January = 0? Wouldn't `Month.of(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));` fail in the case of january?

Answer (score 2):

You can get it one line like this:

```java
String monthName = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)];
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
String getMonthName(int monthNumber) {
    String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();
    int n = monthNumber-1;
    return (n >= 0 && n <= 11) ? months[n] : "wrong number";
}
```

To returns `"September"` with one line:

```
String month = getMonthName(9);
```

Answer (score 2):

**One way:**

We have `Month` API in Java (`java.time.Month`). We can get by using `Month.of(month);`

Here, the `Month` are indexed as numbers so either you can provide by `Month.JANUARY` or provide an index in the above API such as 1, 2, 3, 4.

**Second way:**

```java
ZonedDateTime.now().getMonth();
```

This is available in `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Calender cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)
String[] mons = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH).getShortMonths();
int m = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
String mName = mons[m];
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest Way

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;

int month = 3; // March
System.out.println(new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month-1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns English name of the month.
04 returns APRIL and so on.

```
String englishMonth (int month){
        return Month.of(month);
    }
```

Comment: Simple and direct suggestion, thanks. Your code doesn’t compile. You will either have to declare the return type `Month` or apply `toString` to the result before returning it.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Kotlin extension based on responses in this topic and using the `DateFormatSymbols` answers you get a localized response.

```java
fun Date.toCalendar(): Calendar {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.time = this
    return calendar
}


fun Date.getMonthName(): String {
    val month = toCalendar()[Calendar.MONTH]
    val dfs = DateFormatSymbols()
    val months = dfs.months
    return months[month]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;


Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String currentdate=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM").format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat date =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
Date date1 = new Date();
System.out.println(date.format(date1));
```

Comment: While your answer may be correct, it is of bad quality. Please elaborate on why this answer is correct.

Comment: @SubliemeSiem I'm just trying to change format and simplest way to get it done:
MM- it will return month name in integer like 01, 02, 03.
MMM-it will return month name in short like jan, feb,mar.
MMMM-it will return full month name in string format like January.

Comment: this is the only *CORRECT* answer for formatting dates. use a Date or Calendar object and format it with a formatter. the question itself is *BAD*

Answer (score 0):

For full name of month:

```java
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar.timeInMillis = date
return calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.Long, Locale.ENGLISH)!!.toString()
```

And for short name of month:

```java
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar.timeInMillis = date
return calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH)!!.toString()
```

Answer (score -3):

from the SimpleDateFormat java doc:

```
*         <td><code>"yyyyy.MMMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa"</code>
 *         <td><code>02001.July.04 AD 12:08 PM</code>
 *         <td><code>"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"</code>
 *         <td><code>Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700</code>
```

Comment: I can't see how this answer the question asked.