# Java printf with date and month

Tags: java

```
System.out.printf("Time: %d-%d %02d:%02d"    +            
 calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
 calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
 calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
 calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

That is the code a friend showed me, but how do I get the date to appear in a Format like November 1?

Comment: Use a Date object together with a SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: It's a pain... SDF is a crap and so is `printf`. I wrote an utility allowing to write `myFormatter.format("Time: [d-m HH:MM]", new Date())` and allowing to plug in other formatting strings for the same or different types, but it's not published yet.

Comment: @maaartinus If you could elaborate on the issues you see with SDF in an answer, I believe it would be useful to many readers. Otherwise the OP will leave thinking only "somebody said SDF was crap but I don't know why" (and personally I disagree) and risks avoiding a good tool for no real reason.

Comment: @JasonC You're right... though this theme deserves a length rant more than a SO answer. I wrote an answer concerning `printf`. It's a pain that we got a poor C function remake.`SDF` was not the subject of the question, but my concerns with it are simple: A class which is *both* non-thread-safe and costly to create is a terrible combination.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get month name from Calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832151/how-to-get-month-name-from-calendar)

Answer (score 2):

This is how to do it:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMMMM d" );
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(); // The date you want to format
Date dateToFormat = calendar.getTime();
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format( dateToFormat );
System.out.println( formattedDate );
```

Comment: Can I do it with the calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) etc method? Or do I have to use date format?

Comment: `Calendar.getTime()` gives you a `Date` see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: @user2738201 I have updated my answer adding the way to extract the Date from a Calendar

Answer (score 1):

```
Date d = new Date();
System.out.printf("%s %tB %<td", "Today",  d);
// output : 
//   Today november  01
```

- **%tB** for Locale-specific full month name, e.g. "January", "February".
- **%<td**  *d* for Day of month, formatted as two digits with leading zeros as necessary, *<* for reuse the last parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The [`DateFormat` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26695301/616460) is the way to do this. The [`printf` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26695453/616460) is also good although does not provide locale-specific formats (it provides language-specific names but does not use e.g. the day/month/year ordering that the current locale uses).

You asked in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695254/java-printf-with-date-and-month/26700704#comment41986110_26695301):

> Can I do it with the calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) etc method? Or do I have to use date format?

You don't *have* to use the other methods here, but if you want to use the `Calender` fields, it is up to you to convert the numeric values they provide to strings like "Tuesday" or "November". For that you can use the built in [`DateFormatSymbols`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html), which provides internationalized strings from numbers for dates, in the form of `String` arrays, which you can use the `Calendar` fields to index in to. See [How can I convert an Integer to localized month name in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038570/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-to-localized-month-name-in-java) for example.

Note you can use [`DateFormat.getDateInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance()) to retrieve a pre-made format for the current locale (see the rest of those docs, there are also methods for getting pre-made time-only or date+time formats).

Basically you have the following options:

- `DateFormat` (`SimpleDateFormat` for custom formats)

  - Locale-specific format (e.g. day/month/year ordering): Yes
  - Language-specific names (e.g. English "November" vs. Spanish "Noviembre"): Yes
  - Does the work for you: Yes. This is the best way and will provide a format that the user is used to working with, with no logic needed on your end.
- `printf` date fields

  - Locale-specific format: No
  - Language-specific names: Yes
  - Does the work for you: Partly (up to you to determine field ordering)
- `Calendar` fields with `DateFormatSymbols`

  - Locale-specific format: No
  - Language-specific names: Yes
  - Does the work for you: No
- `Calendar` fields with your own string conversions (like a big `switch` statement):

  - Locale-specific format: No
  - Language-specific names: No
  - Does the work for you: No

Another advantage of `DateFormat`-based formats vs `printf` date fields is you can still define your own field ordering and formats with the `SimpleDateFormat` (just like `printf`) but you can stick to the `DateFormat` interface which makes it easier to pass around and combine with stock date formats like `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM)`.

Check out the [documentation for `DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) for info on the things you can do with it. Check out the [documentation for `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for info on creating custom date formats. Check out this [nice example of date formats](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20140703022925/http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/)) for some example output if you want instant gratification.

Answer (score 1):

There's a direct way how to do it using `printf`, but it's a pain, too:

```
String.printf("Time: %1$td-%1$tm %1$tH:%1$tM", new Date());
```

One problem with it is that it uses 4 formatting strings with the same object, so it needs the `1$` prefix to always access the *first* argument. The other is that I can never remember what letter means what (but maybe that's just me).

Speed could actually be another problem, if you care.

This is documented in the underlying class [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

---

My preffered way would be something like

```
myFormatter.format("Time: [d-m HH:MM]", new Date())
```

where the braces would save us from repeating `$1` and make clear where the argument ends.