# Calendar.getDisplayName returns number

Tags: android, time, calendar

I'm using this method to get MONTH and DAY_OF_WEEK names. On almost all devices it's working perfectly, but on my LG P500 with Android version 2.3.7 instead of the display name I get a number. My conclusion is that the number returned is in fact the index of the DAY or MONTH...for example Wednesday returns 4, Thursday 5 etc... the same thing happend for months display names.

Also it is the same for SHORT and LONG styles.
Anyone knows why this happens?

EDIT:

```
private Locale locale

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   this.user = PreferenceHelper.getUser(getActivity());
   this.club = PreferenceHelper.getSelectedClub(getActivity());
   this.locale = new Locale(PreferenceHelper.getLocale(getActivity()));
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String monthName = c.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, locale);

}
```

I save my locale in the preference. It should always return an locale. I also tried making my locale:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("abc");
```

but it looks like it returns in English if the locale is not valid (on devices that display text and not a number)

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @Nabin what do you mean by that? They should return the same result not depending on the device...Also it's not an Android class it's a class from the Java framework so why should it be different on other devices?

Comment: please fix syntax errors and format your code properly!

Comment: There's some cleaner implementations using SimpleDateFormat in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192781/month-name-as-a-string