# How to show Dutch month using Joda DateTime

Tags: android, datetime, kotlin, jodatime, datetime-format

I'm trying to show dutch months. But the month is printed out in English. This needs to work from Android API 19 and higher.

```
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'

val test = DateTime()

val l = Locale("nl_NL")  // Dutch language, Netherlands country.
val f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM yyyy").withLocale(l)
val text = f.print(test)
```

Prints out:

> 26 Oct 2017

Should be:

> 26 Okt 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the `Locale`'s [2-arg constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#Locale(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), that receives the language and country code in separate parameters:

```
val l = Locale("nl", "NL")
```

With this, the output is:

> 26 okt 2017

In my tests, the output is not in uppercase `Okt` as you wanted, but that's built-in in the API and we have no control over it. If you want `Okt` as output, you'll have to manipulate the string by yourself.

Comment: okt to Okt can be done with substring() and toUpperCase(). There are many  workarounds for this issue.

Comment: In Dutch, months are generally not started with a capital, so the API is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer:

```
    val l = Locale("nl", "NL")
    val f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM yyyy").withLocale(l)

    val dateStr = f.print(dateTime).substring(3, 4).toUpperCase()
    val capitalizedDate = StringBuilder(f.print(dateTime))
    capitalizedDate.setCharAt(3, dateStr[0])

    return capitalizedDate.toString().replace(".", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I already answered to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44285366/1808829). You can get a localized month name using `Calendar` object.

```
private String getMonthName(final int index, final Locale locale, final boolean shortName)
{
    String format = "%tB";

    if (shortName)
        format = "%tb";

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, index);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    return String.format(locale, format, calendar);
}
```

**Example for full month name:**

```
System.out.println(getMonthName(0, new Locale("NL"), false));
```

Result: `januari`

**Example for short month name:**

```
System.out.println(getMonthName(2, new Locale("NL"), true));
```

Result: `jan.`